# Where did IDefaultKeyServices go in ASP.NET Core 2.0? What replaces it?

Tags: security, asp.net-core-2.0

In ASP.NET Core 1.x the IoC container could be used to get a concrete implementation of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.IDefaultKeyServices` but no such interface is registered with the IoC in ASP.NET Core 2.0.  Where did `IDefaultKeyServices` go? Or what replaces it?

The interface looked like this:

```
 public interface IDefaultKeyServices {
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the default Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.IXmlEncryptor
    //     service (could return null).
    IXmlEncryptor GetKeyEncryptor();
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the default Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.IXmlRepository
    //     service (must not be null).
    IXmlRepository GetKeyRepository();
}
```

Microsoft documents the interface [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection.keymanagement.internal.idefaultkeyservices?view=aspnetcore-1.1).

I realize that this interface is in an "Internal" namespace and is subject to change (and change it did!).  But how does one now get the default key repository and the default key encryptor in 2.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IDefaultKeyServices` and its implementation `DefaultKeyServices` were removed with this [commit](https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/commit/ddd041b0f11858fc8d31b9fcf110427145d7a94d).

Instances of `IXmlRepository` and `IXmlEncryptor` could be accessed via `XmlRepository` and `XmlEncryptor` properties of [`KeyManagementOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection.keymanagement.keymanagementoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.0).

[Key storage providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers#data-protection-implementation-key-storage-providers) article lists built-in implementations of `IXmlRepository`. You setup appropriate repository by calling `PersistKeysTo...()` extension method on `IDataProtectionBuilder`, e.g.:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp\"));
```

or

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToRegistry(Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Sample\keys"));
```

[Key Encryption At Rest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-encryption-at-rest#data-protection-implementation-key-encryption-at-rest) article lists built-in implementations of `IXmlEncryptor`. You setup appropriate encryptor by calling `ProtectKeysWith...()` extension method on `IDataProtectionBuilder`, e.g.:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .ProtectKeysWithDpapi();
```

Here is a demo sample (Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection NuGet required):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp\"))
        .ProtectKeysWithDpapi();

    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var options = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<KeyManagementOptions>>();
    var keyManagementOptions = options.Value;

    var xmlRepository = keyManagementOptions.XmlRepository;
    //  Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository
    var repositoryType = xmlRepository?.GetType();

    var xmlEncryptor = keyManagementOptions.XmlEncryptor;
    //  Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlEncryptor
    var encryptorType = xmlEncryptor?.GetType();
}
```

One more useful article in addition to already linked: [Key management extensibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/extensibility/key-management?tabs=aspnetcore2x)